# Odd Issue While Rigging Clothing

Tags: rigging, objects

using Blender 2.93 i parented Mesh to armature, then tried both methods of binding (transfer wieghts and data transfer. but when i test it this is what i get. Any Help would be appreciated. please note i fairly new to blender. and the mesh was made in Marvelous Designer. [image]

Comment: Is there more than 1 clothes object?

Comment: ok just an update , this was caused by the way i exported from Marvelous Designer.
im not really sure why, but i re-exported and it solved the problem. thanks